# How to get a capture group that doesnt always exist?

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex something like

```
(\d\d\d)(\d\d\d)(\.\d\d){0,1}
```

when it matches I can easily get first two groups, but how do I check if third occurred 0 or 1 times.

Also another minor question: in the `(\.\d\d)` I only care about `\d\d` part, any other way to tell regex that `\.\d\d`  needs to appear 0 or 1 times, but that I want to capture only `\d\d` part ?

This was based on a problem of parsing a

> hhmmss

string that has optional decimal part for seconds( so it becomes

> hhmmss.ss

)... I put `\d\d\d` in the question so it is clear about what `\d\d` Im talking about.

Comment: It would be VERY helpful if you can provide some sample input and expected output strings.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
import re

value = "123456.33"

regex = re.search("^(\d\d\d)(\d\d\d)(?:\.(\d\d)){0,1}$", value)

if regex:
    print regex.group(1)
    print regex.group(2)
    if regex.group(3) is not None:
        print regex.group(3)
    else:
        print "3rd group not found"
else:
    print "value don't match regex"
```

Comment: aaah noncapturing group... tnx :D

Comment: `{0,1}` is usually written as `?`

Comment: @thg435, yes. `{0,1}` and `?` are the same. Just kept as it was in question

Comment: I'd like to point out that `regex.group(3) is None` when not found.

Comment: **@JanneKarila for the true solution.** Ideally, `regex.group(3) is None` would have been a distinct answer. The solution provided by [stalk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/821594/stalk) fails to distinguish between captured empty groups and non-captured groups, which absolutely matters in most cases.

Comment: Updated the answer with `regex.group(3) is None`

Comment: I think it should be `is not None`, you are using the group only if it is `None`...

Comment: Stalk, can you reply to @Daniel 's comment?

Comment: @HabeebPerwad updated the answer, `is not None` should be correct